# Overloading ActiveSupport's default to_sentence behaviour

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activesupport

ActiveSupport offers the nice method `to_sentence`. Thus,

```
require 'active_support'
[1,2,3].to_sentence  # gives "1, 2, and 3"
[1,2,3].to_sentence(:last_word_connector => ' and ')  # gives "1, 2 and 3"
```

it's good that you can change the last word connector, because I prefer not to have the extra comma. but it takes so much extra text: 44 characters instead of 11!

**the question**: what's the most ruby-like way to change the default value of `:last_word_connector` to `' and '`?

Comment: this should really be tagged activesupport... don't know why the tag was removed ...

Comment: @Peter, I think this is a two in one question. 1) how do I achieve this with active support. 2) how do I override extensions to the Array class. I think you should consider asking a separate non active support related question for the general pattern

Comment: @sam sounds good! I've put the question about the general pattern here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334569/changing-default-ruby-arguments

Comment: I deleted my answer from here and put it there.

Comment: @Peter, the answer you selected here, sounds like a correct answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334569/changing-default-ruby-arguments , not to this particular problem, in particular this is both more verbose and not that easy to localize.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As an answer to how to override a method in general, a post [here](http://split-s.blogspot.com/2006/01/replacing-methods.html) gives a nice way of doing it. It doesn't suffer from the same problems as the alias technique, as there isn't a leftover "old" method.

Here how you could use that technique with your original problem (tested with ruby 1.9)

```
class Array
  old_to_sentence = instance_method(:to_sentence)
  define_method(:to_sentence) { |options = {}|

    options[:last_word_connector] ||= " and "
    old_to_sentence.bind(self).call(options)
  }
end
```

You might also want read up on [UnboundMethod](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/UnboundMethod.html) if the above code is confusing. Note that old_to_sentence goes out of scope after the end statement, so it isn't a problem for future uses of Array.

Answer (score 12):

Well, it's localizable so you could just [specify a default](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html) 'en' value of ' and ' for `support.array.last_word_connector`

See:

from: conversion.rb

```
def to_sentence(options = {})
...
   default_last_word_connector = I18n.translate(:'support.array.last_word_connector', :locale => options[:locale])
...
end
```

### Step by step guide:

First, Create a rails project

```
rails i18n
```

Next, edit your en.yml file: vim config/locales/en.yml

```
en:
  support:
    array:
      last_word_connector: " and "
```

Finally, it works:

```
 
Loading development environment (Rails 2.3.3)
>> [1,2,3].to_sentence
=> "1, 2 and 3"
```

Comment: How would you do this if you are using activesupport without rails (eg just for a shell script)?

Comment: Rake tasks load the whole environment, for a shell script outside of rails you can always do I18n.load_path << "filename_with_localization.yml"

Answer (score -1):

```
 class Array
   alias_method :old_to_sentence, :to_sentence
   def to_sentence(args={})
     a = {:last_word_connector => ' and '}
     a.update(args) if args
     old_to_sentence(a)
   end
 end
```

Comment: the trouble with monkey patching is that you are building a house of cards, next time someone monkey patches this in the same way you will have an infinite loop. In this particular case monkey patching is not really needed, cause there is a supported way of achieving the same goal.

Comment: true, didn't know activesupport did something to support super. that's definitely the best way, then.